# Do complex nos makes sense only if they exist in pairs (as conjugates)?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am not sure if this is correct question but please reply so i can make sense out of complex numbers. Thanks.

.

It just occured to me. 
In case of x^2+1=0.

We have i and -i roots and if multiplied we get magnitude i.e. 1.

WOW! i think there should be reasonable explanation to this..

Comment: What do you mean by "...exist in pairs"?

Comment: like if i solve x^2+1=0 i get +i and -i.. let me update question..

Comment: here, in you case: $i=0+i$ and $-i=0+(-i)$. Furthermore, $0\in\mathbb{C}$ as $0=0+i0$

Comment: Guess #2 for answering your "question": If $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a root of quadratic equation, the also his conjugate, $\bar{z}$ is a root.

Comment: No complex numbers have many uses not only to solve the roots of a quadratic equation.  I personally use them to design filters but for some examples of how and why they are used in physics and engineering [see here](http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/211/complex_review.pdf).

Comment: @user119587 Any polynomial that only has real coefficients will have complex roots that occur in conjugate pairs. See if you can construct polynomials whose roots do not occur in conjugate pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is an answer to your question, but I am quite sure you will like this, given your enthusiasm about $i(-i) = 1$ (which i quite like too!). So here goes.

Pick any equation of the form $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + ... + a_0 = 0$. (So in your case $n = 2$, $a_1 = 0$, $a_0 = 1$.)

A nice thing about complex numbers is that this equation has $n$ solutions in $\mathbb{C}$.This is known as the  Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, see for instance Wikipedia. Let's call these solutions $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$.

Now the nice thing I was refering to in the beginning is this:

If you sum all the $\lambda_i$ you get $a_{n-1}$ (in your case $ i + (-i) = 0$).

If you sum all the products of two of the $\lambda_i$ (so $\lambda_1\lambda_2 + \lambda_1\lambda_3 + ... +\lambda_1\lambda_n + \lambda_2\lambda_3+ ... + \lambda_{n-1}\lambda_n$) you get $a_{n-2}$

If you sum all the products of three of the $\lambda_i$ (if applicable) you get $a_{n-3}$

If you sum all the products of four of the $\lambda_i$ (if applicable) you get $a_{n-4}$

...

If you take the product of all $n$ $\lambda_i$ you get $a_0$ (in your case $i(-i)=1$).

Put like this it sounds pretty mind-blowing, but if we reverse our perspective and start with the complex numbers $\lambda_1 \ldots \lambda_n$ there is an easy explanation:
obviously all $\lambda_i$ are zero's of the equation
$$(x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)...(x - \lambda_n) = 0$$
and all the above follows by expanding out the product on the left.

Comment: Thanks really great.. It was quite obvious until you put it in equation form at then end. cool..

Answer (score 0):

Here is one explanation:

Suppose $f(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x + a_0$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, and suppose $u+iv$ is a root of $f$ for some real $u,v$. Then $u-iv$ is also a root of $f$.

This is because, if $u,v$ are any real numbers, and $r$ is any non-negative integer, then $(u+iv)^r = U + iV \implies (u-iv)^r = U - iV$. Hence if $f(u+iv) = U+iV$, then $f(u-iv) = U-iV$; so if $U + iV = 0$, then $U-iV = 0$ too.

Note that this doesn't apply if any of the coefficients $a_r$ is not a real number.